# What kept 19th century Europe's workers going?

Tags: europe, 19th-century, industrial-history

If the salary of an industrial worker was so low that they barely survived and couldn't even dream of ascending to upper classes¹, what kept them from revolting all the time? One could argue that there was always a great number of unemployed workers just waiting to substitute employed ones when these went on strike, but how did those unemployed workers survive if they had no income?

¹Mentioned in Hobsbawm's "The Age of Revolution: 1789-1848" and further explained in "The Age of Capital: 1848-1875"

Comment: People in general are not inclined towards violence.

Comment: Do you have any backing sources to claim this?

Comment: Yes. I've met thousands of people in my live, and have never even once been murdered. Source: Me. How about you?

Comment: Even the most violent places on earth these days have a murder rate below 200 murders / 100,000 population. [For Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_by_murder_rate) the city with the highest murder rate these days is Caracas with 119 murders per 100,000. That means that there are 999,881 who were not murdered. [Here is](http://marginalrevolution.com/marginalrevolution/2011/06/long-term-trend-in-homicide-rates.html) a more historical source. People are just not that violent. Most people are not killers. It's a lot of work organize peasants into a viable military organization.

Comment: Violence does not necessarily correlate with murder. Also, you must remember that 19th century Europe was known to have lots of revolutions, so it was almost certain that a big part of the industrial worker's class had living memory of a revolution, and most certainly could think of doing another. Why they didn't is what I'm asking for.

Comment: I'd challenge the claim that workers couldn't dream of ascending to the upper classes, or more commonly, to middle class prosperity.  Even if it wasn't common, it did happen.

Comment: According to Marx (in spirit if not in letter): "Religion is what keeps the poor from murdering the rich."

Comment: @jamesqf The sources I mentioned say it did happen, but it was very rare... As I don't have any numbers to show, your challenge is a valid one. I can't seem to find statistics about this, though :(

Comment: @Júlio Zampietro: Sure, just as it's very rare to win the lottery, but people still keep buying tickets.

Comment: Those industrial workers moved to the towns to get away from extreme poverty in rural areas. As far as they were concerned they were much better off in towns, with better working conditions (a factory with a roof) and a steady income (as opposed to starving if your cow died). It's a relative thing. People still do it, you know.

Comment: @RedSonja In one of the books I mentioned the author says that it was a common belief that agricultural workers were better off than industrial ones, health-wise. Apparently some even said that for a country to have a strong military it needed to have many agricultural workers, because industrial ones simply couldn't handle it. Also, another common belief at the beginning of the Industrial Revolution was that agricultural workers were 'lazy', because they weren't used to constant work in every season, so it could be argued that in rural areas people worked less than in industrial ones.

Comment: @Júlio Zampietro I come from a farm myself. I can assure you it is hard, endless and dirty work in all weathers. Only growers do not work in winter, and in the old days if the crops failed they just starved. Farmers work all hours every day, and more at harvest time. Before machines it was back-breaking and dangerous. Remember only the oldest son got the farm. The rest were thrown out or had to work as serfs.

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be an opinion in historical and military circles that people who are barely getting by don't revolt. They are too busy putting food on the table. You get a revolution when people have a hope that things are getting better, and when that hope is frustrated. Not absolute poverty but **relative** and **subjective** poverty.

There is another line of thought which relates revolution to the bread prices, so that's not the only explanation for revolutions ...

I don't have time to look for many sources, just [this](http://www.worldbank.org/en/news/feature/2015/10/21/middle-class-frustration-that-fueled-the-arab-spring) for the first case and [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/newsnight/paulmason/2011/04/revolutions_and_the_price_of_b.html) for the second.